# Firefox has different pixel size?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have to use fixed height for certain layout (google maps with form in the sidebar) elements and I noticed that 600px height in Firefox is much much bigger than in other browsers (Chrome, IE 8). The Firefox 600 px is actually displayed as cca 690 px! Even the google map tiles are rescaled, so they display the same in both FF and Chrome. And even the Web developer toolbar / Misc / Ruler shows 600 px instead.

1. How is that possible? Which setting is doing that? I thought that pixel is quite clear unit and it is reliable to be a real pixel.
2. Can I reset it for Firefox to the normal height, so that it looks the same in all browsers? I have problems with this because in Firefox everything can fit into those "600" (= 690) pixels, but not in other browsers. I would like the size to be similar compared to form fields that can actually fit in.
3. Is it desirable to do it? Or not because it will also break the sizes of everything else (font size) which users are already used to, it can break the browser settings and user expectations related to other sites etc.

PS: Note that I already did <kbd>Ctrl-0</kbd> (or menu view > zoom > reset) in FF and similarly in Chrome.

Comment: the only difference (that i know of) in pixel count between Chrome and Firefox is how they count the borders, so i guess you need to either: 1. reset the zoom on both browsers to make sure that both are at 100% 2. check if you have any specific moz css that could affect your pages. Also, make sure that you have all the css vendor-prefixes where they need to be. not all browsers have implemented all the css changes.

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu nope, it is not caused by the border (the border is only 1px and also note that the images - google maps tiles - are rescaled in FF). The zoom is already reset in all browsers.

Comment: could you post the css for the element that's messing up the design ? did you check that you have the vendor prefixed versions of css rules as well as non prefixed ones where it could impact the design ?

Comment: what css and what element you speak about?

Comment: I guess the whole page in jsfiddle would be best to both replicate the problem and try to resolve it. It could also help testing in other browsers in case it happens there two. There are many css properties that could affect a design and we can't really help until we see what you use. And I said element because I didn't exactly understand what part of your page is not being displayed correctly (again, could be better with jsfiddle or pictures)

Comment: **There is no particular page where this happens.** It happens on **every page**, with just the default setting of both browsers.

Comment: Then show any one of those pages ... or give the css of whatever element of the page shows up bigger ...

Comment: do the contents of the sidebar look the same? Is any text carrying over to the next line in firefox? It may be overflow from other properties being rendered differently that are affecting the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where every element on Firefox (OSX) was smaller than any other browser (OSX or PC). I realized the problem came from the font-sizing I gave in my CSS.
I was able to solve the issue (on my own site at least) by changing:

```
html{
    font: 1em/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

to

```
html{
    font: 16px/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I was using `em`s to scale a lot of my content, and I guess if you don't specify how big an `em` is, Firefox will make it up on its own sizing rules.

Comment: nope, this is not the problem, since EVERYTING, including images, google maps etc. shows bigger in Firefox.

Comment: Weird. Yeah, it was everything that was affected for me too, but smaller instead of larger.

Comment: The same happens with me, but on firefox, everything is smaller